# Простой пример с одним нейроном.

Tags: c, c++, нейронные-сети, fann

Нужен простейший пример с реализацией:

```
Цветок
параметры:
цвет   +1.0
запах  + 2.0

Далее ввести объект с оценкой
оценить(evaluated)
цвет   -1.0
запах  + 2.0
```

Нейрон должен вернуть +3.

На библиотеке fann или opennn(или иной высокоуровневой).
Собственно никак не могу перейти к практике, так как нет простейший примеров в этих библиотеках.
Документация очень скудная.

К тому же библиотека fann выбрасывает исключения из dll(fanndouble.dll,fannfloat.dll) на функции `fann_train_on_file()`
При копировании примеров с их сайта.

Comment: а почему 3? и почему 2? насколько я знаю, весовой коэффициент обычно от 0 до 1.

Answer (score -2):

```
int sravn(int arg1,int arg2)
{
int a,b,c
a=arg1/1;
b=arg2/2;
c=a+=b;
if(c>1)
{c=1-=c}
return c;
}
```

В арг1 записываем цвет сравнимаемого,а в арг2 - запах.
На выходе полуаем отношение нейрона к цветку.

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ - как ваш ответ решает задачу автора вопроса?

Comment: Очень просто решает. В арг1 вводим цвет сравнимаемого в арг2 запах сравнимаемого.На выходе получаем отношение нейрона к цветку.

Comment: Но есть некоторые недочеты все же. Позже исправлю их.

Comment: Перенесите комментарии в ответ [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/694105/edit).

Comment: Недочет в том,что цветок может ему нравится больше чем тот который должен быть самым лучшим.

Comment: зачем юзать библиотеку,если можно без нее?